NextJs: <Script> tag doesn't load third party script as expected
I'm building a chat bot function by integrating with Genesys SDK into my NextJs React app. It's pretty straight forward - just need to embed a little script into a page. For example, here's a basic working example:
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      (function (g, e, n, es, ys) {
        g['_genesysJs'] = e;
        g[e] = g[e] || function () {
          (g[e].q = g[e].q || []).push(arguments)
        };
        g[e].t = 1 * new Date();
        g[e].c = es;
        ys = document.createElement('script'); ys.async = 1; ys.src = n; ys.charset = 'utf-8'; document.head.appendChild(ys);
      })(window, 'Genesys', 'https://apps.mypurecloud.com.au/genesys-bootstrap/genesys.min.js', {
        environment: 'xxx',
        deploymentId: 'xxxx'
      });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

The <script> in the above code fetches the Genesys js bundle and renders chat widget as expected.
However, I couldn't get it to work in my NextJs app. Things I have tried so far:

NextJs's <Script src="/...chat-script.js"/> component in the chat page, tried all loading strategies
NextJs's <Script src="/...chat-script.js"/> component in the global layout page, tried all loading strategies
Script with dangerouslySetInnerHTML which loads the chat script

None of the above worked. When the page loads, I can see it does load the initial Genesys JS bundle, which appends the head with more  tags which should load more scripts, but those appended scripts don't seem to be loaded. E.g. the initial script loads Genesys.min.js which should then loads Messenger.min.js etc., but in NextJs app, the those additional scripts are not loaded.
What could be a solution to this?
